# Scala csv file read and display the data in new column

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe

I am new to Scala. I need to read data from csv file which has two header columns named Name and Marks, based on the Marks column I want to show the result in a 3rd column; pass or fail (<35 fail, >35pass).

The data looks like this:

```
Name,Marks 
x,10
y,50
z,80
```

Result should be:

```
Name Marks Result
x    10     Fail
Y    50     Pass
z    80     Pass
```

Comment: What have you done and where are you having problems? What is your specific question?

Comment: Show us the code that _doesn't_ work. That way we can see where you're going off track and can offer better solutions to clarify the issues involved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local")
           .appName("").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C:/temp").getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.option("header",true).csv("file path")
val resul = df.withColumn("Result", when(col("Marks").cast("Int")>=35, "PASS").otherwise("FAIL"))
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please describe how this should solve the current question and, when appropriate, how your answer is different from other answers offered.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the csv file with header, then add a column by using `when` and `otherwise` to give different values depending on the marks.

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("/path/to/csv") // read csv
val df2 = df.withColumn("Result", when($"Marks" < 35, "Fail").otherwise("Pass"))
```